# Security credentials for filepicker.makeDropPane

Tags: filepicker.io

The [drag-drop pane widget documentation](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets-droppane)  does not reference security policies or signatures.

I expected makeDropPane to take policy and signature options like the Javascript API.

Are secure uploads available via filepicker.makeDropPane()? If not, is it otherwise possible to have a standalone drag-drop pane that uses security policies?

Comment: Good catch, that was an oversight on our part. Should be rolling out soon

Answer (score 0):

Following up, this code has been pushed, and passing a security policy and signature are now possible for makeDropPane.